# Laravel 9: how to prevent eager loading during unit-tests?

Tags: laravel, unit-testing, eager-loading

Consider the following `Model`:

```
class Selection extends Model
{
    use HasFactory, SoftDeletes;

    protected $table = '...';

    public function subjects(): HasMany
    {
        return $this->hasMany(SelectionSubject::class);
    }
}
```

And I'm getting `subjects` eagerly like so:

```
$selection->subjects()->get()->pluck('code')->toArray()
```

Which works fine except when I try to unit test it, it gives me the following error:

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException : SQLSTATE[42P01]: Undefined table: 7 ERROR:  relation "subjects_table" does not exist
```

So apparently it tried to load `subjects` from the database, which does not exist for unit tests.

I've tried the following approach:

```
public function boot()
{
        Model::preventLazyLoading();

        Model::handleLazyLoadingViolationUsing(function ($model, $relation) {
            $class = get_class($model);

            info("Attempted to lazy load [{$relation}] on model [{$class}].");
        });
}
```

But for some reason it doesn't work for me - the exception is not being raised and it keeps trying to hit the database.

Any ideas of how to actually prevent `subjects` from being loaded from the database in unit tests?

Comment: First of all, you are not "_eager loading_", you are literally using a relationship, but definitely not [eager loading](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) it. Second, you have to have the database available, even if it is a "unit test" and that code (not the test, but the tested code) uses your models. Do not mock them, just use factories and have fake data on them. That is what you have to have and it will work flawlessly and every time. Even if it is a "unit test", use `\Tests\TestCase` and not the PHPUnit's `TestCase`